# I load the full jQuery library, but I only use Ajax and selectors. Better shorter code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors

I created a star-rating voting system based in jQuery, I load the full jQuery JS library, but I found that I only two features of it:

- the simple Ajax method: `$.ajax({url:"dosomething.php",cache:0,data:n,success:function(t)`
- and the selectors: `$(document).ready(function()... $(".stars").hover(function... $(this).prevAll()...`

I'm not a JavaScript expert, and I wondered if I can substitute the simple Ajax method and the selectors by short JavaScript code.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, of course you can. But you have to consider if you want to create a jquery plugin/extension of something independent of jquery (or anything else). Ask yourself "why"?. However, writing everything from scratch does not make it more usable IMHO - at the end of the day, it will break the DRY principle. And you might need to allocate more follow-up time to keep it up to date. You better target several different frameworks in different packages if you want to.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use jQuery as there are alternatives to many functions jQuery used to perform.

For ajax your can use [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). For selectors you can use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Another alternative is to use a lightweight library like [Zepto.js](https://zeptojs.com/) which has the same syntax as jQuery. You can choose which module you want to use.

Finally, you can check http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ for specific jQuery alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting that pages may need to render using HTML returned as JavaScript in certain cases. XMLHttpRequest cannot return HTML as script. jQuery's AJAX can.